# Javascript - Array - Assigning values from one array to strings in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hopefully the title is somewhat clear...dont know how to be more specific.

Here is my problem:
I have several different variables that should be passed into the localstorage from one to another Html page. 
On one (of many) pages, I can (with clickevents) changes values, which should be saved afterwards and being loaded on the next page. If there is no value other then the start value "0", the value 0 should be saved, so the var does not get undefined.
Technically the localstorage thing is working with the following code within a function : `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function():`

```
var XXX;
if (localStorage.XXX> 0){
    XXX= Number(localStorage.XXX);
} else {
    XXX = 0;
}
document.getElementById("XXX").innerText = XXX;
```

This whole code is most probably not the prettiest thing you have ever seen, but it is working. As I have several variables, which get more and more, I think it would be good to put all of this copy / pasted code for each variable into a function... I tried many things but nothing is working, I do not even get it with the help of ctrl+Shift+I... here is what I was trying:

```
var resource = ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"];
var localStorageResource = [localStorage.XXX, localStorage.YYY, localStorage.ZZZ];
function getLocalStorage() {
    for (var i = 0; i < resource.length; i++){
        if (localStorageResource[i] > 0){
            resource[i] = Number(localStorageResource[i]);
        } else {
            resource[i] = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("resource[i]").innerText = resource[i];
```

So as you can see, the code is not really different, I just placed the variables and their respective localstorage values into two different arrays.
I am not able to understand why the variable XXX get overwriten with the actual value, instead of the value getting assigned to the variable... which is working fine in the "non flexible" solution.

*Just to give you the background:
It is all about harvesting resources on one page or another (different resources on different locations) and bringing all these information, on the other html pages, to do something with these resources.... 
Right now I am using vanilla Javascript with the exception of easelJS for some canvas stuff*

I would very much appreciate your advice and hope to learn a ton from your answers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"resource[i]"` is not doing what you think

Comment: **I am not able to understand why the variable XXX get overwriten with the actual value** - what variable `XXX`? `resource` is an array of `strings` not an array of `vars`

Comment: getElementById("**resource[i]**") What are you trying to do here? This will select element of id "resources[i]" as in `<div id="resources[i]"`

Comment: @ epascarello: Thanks, this was pretty obvious even for me. :-)
@ Craicerjack: sorry for using the wrong terminus. I think you got the question anyway. @ Zeus: With the code line you are refering to, I am able to push the information for the if statement to a specific span, to update the value (number) writen in it, to be displayed for the user....Thank you all 3 for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better try with an object and iterate over the keys (act as the variable names for your example)

```
var resource = {"XXX": 0, "YYY": 0, "ZZZ": 0};

function getLocalStorage() {
    for (var i in resource){ //Variable "i" will be "XXX", "YYY" and "ZZZ" strings in each iteration
        resource[i] = localStorage.getItem(i) || 0; //In the first iteration will assign localStorage.getItem("XXX") to resource.XXX, and so on...
        document.getElementById(i).innerText = resource[i]; //In the first iteration will get element by id="XXX" and assign the value of resource.XXX, and so on...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you edrian, your code is working as intended -> the values get transfered as needed! Just as comment from my side: Seems to me, that the variables that are combined within the object are "different", from the standard variables --> var XXX, var YYY, var ZZZ are different variable then the 3 in the object. Therefore I was a little bit confused when adding your code in the first place. Marked as accepted answer!

Comment: Sorry, but I need to ask another question, in the direction of the comment above: Within my js file, I had (before your help) the variables var XXX, var YYY, var ZZZ which were used somewhen afterwards the whole localstorage thing. F.e. XXX+YYY+ZZZ = AAA. With the solution of yours implemented, I cannot do this anymore, but I need to change the formular to resource["XXX"] + resource["YYY"] + resource["ZZZ"] = AAA.... is this the only way or can I get the information out of the object, back to the "standard" variable? Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeB, as you wanted to use a more dynamic approach for your code it was better to use object keys instead of variables, because in this way its more simple to iterate. To access the object values you could do either `resource.XXX` or `resource['XXX']`. In your original example you used `var resource = ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"]`, so the values in the array were strings, not the variables XXX, YYY, ZZZ, maybe that confused everyone. You probable wanted `var resource = [XXX, YYY, ZZZ]` where XXX, YYY, ZZZ are variables defined before your code.

Comment: @MikeB but yes, now you can do something like `var AAA = resource.XXX + resource.YYY + resource.ZZZ`.